# Correct Flutter navigation practice in Drawer

Tags: flutter, navigator, drawer

Quick question on navigation between Flutter screens from a re-usable drawer in Material App.

I have a drawer set up with two navigation options in a list to Screen1() and Screen2() eg:

```
    // Go to Screen 1
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Screen1()),
    //
    // Go to Screen 2
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Screen2()),
```

If a user repeatedly navigates between Screen1 and Screen2 via the drawer, will this create an inefficient and endless stack of screens? My intention was to change the drawer on each screen - to use Navigator.pop() so that the user could go back to the other screen, but as I understand it, Navigator.pop() would only destroy the drawer itself - not the screen!

This seems a bit weird to me. What would you recommend I do in the drawer to keep things efficient? Can I code navigator pop to break out of the drawer to pop the actual screen?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of pushAndRemoveUnitl you can use pushReplacement. that replaces the previous screen with a new one that prevents the endless stack.
do upvote if useful :)

Comment: Thanks Yash. This worked efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html):

> Push the given route onto the navigator, and then remove all the
> previous routes until the predicate returns true.

If you'd like to remove every previous route, the second argument, `predicate`, should be like this: `(_) => false`. There's also a [named](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) variant.